# TabHost inside Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to create a tabHost inside a Fragment, so I can create a tabs inside that fragment I've tried changing the extends to android.support.v4.app.Fragment but then the complete app won't build. This issue I have is the following:

```
wrong 2nd argument type. found'android.app.fragment' required 'android.support.v4.app.fragment'
```

This is the code I wrote:

```
public class TimeTableFragment extends Fragment {
FragmentNameFactory nameFactory = new FragmentNameFactory();
String body;
String major;
String status;
private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;
public TimeTableFragment(){

}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceStatus){
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setFragmentName(nameFactory.getNameNL(7));
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ftimetable, container, false);
    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) view.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);
    mTabHost.setup();
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("fragmentb").setIndicator("Fragment B"));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("fragmentc").setIndicator("Fragment C"));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("fragmentd").setIndicator("Fragment D"));


    return view;
}
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstance){
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstance);
}
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstance){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstance);
}}
```

The .xml (ftimetables):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TabWidget
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@android:id/tabs">
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent">
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

I hope someone can help me fix this issue!

Answer (score 0):

change your TimeTableFragment import code

```
import android.app.fragment(x)
import android.support.v4.app.fragment(o)
```